# bash script with grep command not

Tags: grep

I have this part of shell script :

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
currentDate=$(date +%F)

echo $currentDate
command="grep $currentDate"
gcs3='s3://gc-reporting-pud-production/splunk_printer_log_files'
gcs3ls='aws s3 ls 's3://gc-reporting-pud-production/splunk_printer_log_files/SOUTH_ASIA/' --recursive '
ssyss3=s3://ssyssplunk

gcs3Current=$($gcs3ls|$command|sed 's/^.*\(splunk_printer.*\)/\1/g')

SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
s3ls='aws s3 ls --human-readable --summarize 's3://ssyssplunk/' --recursive'
echo "ls: " $s3ls
egrepCommand="'$currentDate|Total'"
echo "grep: " $egrepCommand
totalSize=$($s3ls|egrep $currentDate\|Total|awk -F 'Total Size:' '{print $2}'|sed '/^$/d')
echo "total size: "  $totalSize
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

and im getting this error :

> 2019-05-27 ls:  aws s3 ls --human-readable --summarize
>   s3://ssyssplunk/ --recursive grep:  '2019-05-27|Total'
>   ./copyFilesFromS13.sh: line 54: aws s3 ls --human-readable --summarize
>   s3://ssyssplunk/ --recursive: No such file or directory total size:

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: it is not answering my question

Comment: I see several errors, including anti-pattern “use of `ls` in a script”, this has lead to treating `total size` as a file-name.

Comment: so what is the best way to do it ?

Comment: It can't find the command "aws" - can you run the command outside the script from the same location

Comment: i did and it is working.
@muru suggested that it is because of the IFS that im using to ignore spaces so i changed the order and pasted the commands after IFS=$SAVEIFS
so it now looks like :
IFS=$SAVEIFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
s3ls='aws s3 ls --human-readable --summarize 's3://ssyssplunk/' --recursive'
echo "ls: " $s3ls
egrepCommand="'$currentDate|Total'"
echo "grep: " $egrepCommand
totalSize=$($s3ls|egrep $currentDate\|Total|awk -F 'Total Size:' '{print $2}'|sed '/^$/d')
echo "total size: "  $totalSize

so now there is no error but it is stuck on "totalSize"

Answer (score 0):

You have set IFS to just the newline and backspace. So, `$s3ls`, after expansion and word splitting, will be `aws s3 ls --human-readable --summarize s3://ssyssplunk/ --recursive` taken as a single word. Bash tries to execute this single word as a command, instead of executing `aws` with a bunch of arguments.

You really shouldn't be storing commands in variables. [Use arrays, instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444949/70524):

```
s3ls=(aws s3 ls --human-readable --summarize 's3://ssyssplunk/' --recursive)
#...
totalSize=$("${s3ls[@]}" | ...)
```

Comment: well, i moved it after this line :
IFS=$SAVEIFS
there is no error now but nothing happens... it looks like it stuck